# How many $\overline{a}\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/91\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$ pass the Fermat and Miller-Rabin primability tests?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, computer-algebra-systems, primality-test

Let $$\text{F}_{91}:=\left\{\overline{a}\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times:91\text { passes the Fermat primality test to base }a\right\}$$ and $$\text{MF}_{91}:=\left\{\overline{a}\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times:91\text { passes the Miller-Rabin primality test to base }a\right\}$$
How do we calculate $|\text{F}_{91}|$ and $|\text{MF}_{91}|$? Starting with the [Fermat primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test#Algorithm_and_running_time): As described in the Wikipedia article, the algorithm depends on a parameter $k$. In each iteration (there are at most $k$ iterations), a random variable $a\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$ is chosen and testet for $$a^{91-1}\equiv1\text{ mod }91$$ If this test fails, the algorithm stops and yields that $91=7\cdot 13$ is not prime. However, I'm not sure how to calculate $|\text{F}_{91}|$ since the test depends on some randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The randomness (or more likely pseudo-randomness) that one uses in the application of the tests shall be ignored here.

"The Fermat test to base $a$" is specifically whether $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, like the "Miller-Rabin test to base $a$" (also called strong Fermat test) is whether $a^m\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ or $a^{2^j\cdot m} \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$ for one $j \in \{0,\dotsc,k-1\}$, where $n-1 = 2^k\cdot m$ with $m\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$.

So the question is, for how many $\overline{a} \in (\mathbb{Z}/91\mathbb{Z})^\times$ do we have

- $a^{90} \equiv 1 \pmod{91}$, resp.
- $a^{45} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{91}$.

Since $91 = 7\cdot 13$, the numbers are not hard to find.

Comment: Use the Chinese remainder theorem. You look at each prime factor separately (generally, the prime powers dividing $n$), and glue the things together with the CRT.

Comment: Let's do it with Fermat's theorem: $$a^{90}\equiv \left(a^6\right)^{15}\equiv 1\mod 7$$ and $$a^{90}=\left(a^{12}\right)^7a^6\equiv a^6\mod 13$$ But that's still not that easy to write down, which $1\le a\le 91$ fulfill this property.

Comment: You don't need to find _which_, only _how many_. How many residues modulo $13$ satisfy $a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$?

Comment: You have $k$ residues modulo $7$ that satisfy $a^{90}\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. and $m$ residues modulo $13$ with $a^{90} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$. Then you have $k\cdot m$ residues modulo $7\cdot 13$ with $a^{90} \equiv 1 \pmod{91}$.

Comment: You are only looking at the remainders modulo $7$ there. There are only $7$ such, one of them has $a^{90}\equiv 0 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: There are only 7 remainders modulo $7$, but for all numbers $a\in\left\{1,\ldots, 91\right\}$ it holds $$a^{90}\text{ mod }7=\begin{cases}1&\text{, if }7\nmid a\\0&\text{, else}\end{cases}$$ So, $78$ such $a$ fulfill this congruence. What's wrong?

Comment: The whole point of the factorisation is that you don't look at the remainders modulo $n$, but at the remainders modulo the prime (power) factors. If you have $k$ remainders $a_1,\dotsc,a_k$ modulo $7$ with $a_i^{90}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, and $m$ remainders $b_1,\dotsc,b_m$ modulo $13$ with $b_j^{90}\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$, the Chinese remainder theorem tells you that for each combination $(i,j)$, there is exactly one remainder $c_{ij}$ modulo $91$ with $c_{ij}\equiv a_i\pmod{7}$ and $c_{ij}\equiv b_j\pmod{13}$. Thus the $k\cdot m$ remainders $c_{ij},1\leqslant i\leqslant k,1\leqslant j\leqslant m$ are

Comment: the solutions of $c^{90} \equiv 1 \pmod{91}$.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what I do? There are $91-13=78$ numbers $a\in\left\{1,\ldots,91\right\}$ with $a^{90}\equiv 1\text{ mod }7$ and there are $(91-7)/2=42$ numbers $b\in\left\{1,\ldots,91\right\}$ with $b^{90}\equiv 1\text{ mod }13$ - How do I need to interpret this result?

Comment: No. There are six numbers $a\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with $a^{90}\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. And there are six numbers $b\in \{0,1,2,\dotsc,11,12\}$ with $b^{90}\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$. You don't look at the remainders modulo $91$ when you solve the congruence modulo $p$, but only at the remainders modulo $p$.

Comment: Now I understand what you're trying to say to me. Any chance to count all $b\in\left\{1,\ldots,13\right\}$ with $b^6\equiv 1\text{ mod }13$ without testing them? [May I recommend we delete all that unnecessary comments?]

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way to count the residues $b$ modulo $p^k$ with $b^m \equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$. Note that the remainders coprime to $p$ form a cyclic group of order $(p-1)p^{k-1}$. And in a cyclic group of order $r$, there are exactly $\gcd(r,m)$ elements with $b^m = 1$. You can generalise that, for every $g$, there are either $0$ or $\gcd(r,m)$ elements with $b^m = g$. [And yes to deleting superfluous comments.]

Comment: Okay, we know that $$\varphi (n)=\left|\left\{k\in\mathbb{N}:k<n\wedge\gcd (k,n)=1\right\}\right|=\left|\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times\right|$$ (where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function). We also know, that $\varphi (p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$ for every prime $p$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. There are $\gcd\left((p-1)p^{k-1},n\right)$ elements $\overline{a}\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$ with $a^n\equiv 1\text{ mod }p^k$. What about the other elements $\overline{b}\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)$. Why does it hold $b^n\not\equiv 1\text{ mod }p^k$ for them?

Comment: Don't mix $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^\times$. The latter is a cyclic group (for odd primes $p$, I forgot to mention that restriction in the previous comment, $p = 2$ is different), the former generally not. When $\gcd(b,n) > 1$, then you have $\gcd(b^m,n) > 1$ for all $m > 0$, so the remainder of $b^m$ can then never be $1$. If $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, then it follows that $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$ for every prime power $p^k$ dividing $n$. Hence $p\nmid a$ for every prime $p\mid n$ in that case.

Comment: [Miller-Rabin-Test]: We do it in the same way: $$a^{45}\equiv\pm 1\text{ mod }91\Leftrightarrow a^{45}\equiv\pm 1\text{ mod }7,13$$ Since $$a^{45}=\left(a^6\right)^7a^3\equiv a^3\text{ mod }7\Leftrightarrow\overline{a}\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$$ and $$a^{45}=\left(a^{12}\right)^3a^9\equiv a^9\text{ mod }13\Leftrightarrow\overline{a}\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$$ there are $\gcd(3,7-1)=3$ elements with $a^{45}\equiv 1\text{ mod }7$ and $\gcd(9,13-1)=3$ elements with $a^{45}\equiv 1\text{ mod }13$. What about $\equiv -1$?

Comment: Conveniently, $(-1)^{2m+1} = -1$, which gives a relation between the solutions of $a^{2m+1}\equiv 1$ and $a^{2m+1} \equiv -1$.

Comment: Please explain more about that relationship.

Comment: How is $(-a)^{2m+1}$ related to $a^{2m+1}$?

Comment: So, $a^{2m+1}\equiv -1\Leftrightarrow -a^{2m+1}\equiv 1$?

Comment: Yes. With or without parentheses. So the number is the same for $1$ and $-1$ (since the exponent is odd).

Comment: Thanks again. For the sake of completeness: The solution is $$\left|\text{FM}_{91}\right|=18$$